# Python: form matrix from lists of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data types

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
C=[[0 2]
 [1 2]
 [2 1]]
```

I want to form a `new_matrix` with the following output

```
       index    new_value1      new_value2
1       1        ['A','C']        [0,2]
2       2        ['B','C']        [1,2]
3       3        ['A','B']        [2,1]
```

where the `index` column has the values from the `A` list, `new_value1` has the values from the `B` list and `new_value2` has the values from the `C` list. The values are in an iterative order.

Any help would be much appreaciated.

Comment: Firstly, you want a `DataFrame`, not a matrix. Have you tried using the `DataFrame` constructor? `pd.DataFrame({'index':A, 'new_value1':B, 'new_value2':C})`

Answer (score 2):

Put your variables in a dictionary, and create a data frame using that dictionary:

```
a = dict(
    index=[1,2,3],
    new_value1=[['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']],
    new_value2=[[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
)
pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer however I have a problem since new_value2 is not 1 dimentional and I get 'Data must be 1-dimensiona'l error

Comment: I am not sure about your error. The code I posted works for me in Python 2.7

Comment: as u can see new_value2 has no comma separator between the inner lists

Comment: Yes, I had to modify your list `C` because it would raise a `SyntaxError`